# "Орать благим матом" — происхождение выражения

Tags: фразеология

Мат, как известно, речь совершенно не благостная. Так почему же говорят "орать благим матом" или просто "блажить"? Чем "благой мат" отличается от просто мата?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Благим матом | newslab.ru](http://newslab.ru/blog/415266)

Речь не о том "мате". Фасмер приводит некоторые предположения о том, от каких «матов» могли произойти выражения «кричать благим матом, скакать лихим матом»: от итальянского matto — «безумный, помешанный», или древнеиндийского mimati — «блеет, кричит», или арабского еs sah mat — «король умер», родившего слово «шахматы»."матом" - как безумный, в страхе (перед смертью).

Благий или благой по Далю - злой, сердитый, упрямый, упорный, своенравный, неугомонный, беспокойный; дурной, тяжелый, неудобный.Блажь — дурь, шаль, дурость; упорство, упрямство, своенравие; юродство и так далее. Это на церковном языке благой значит добрый, хороший, путный, полезный, добродетельный, доблестный, от благо — добро.

У Даля "Кричать благим или недаровым матом"- взывать изо всей силы о помощи. Горланит пустым матом. Скачет лихим матом, во всю прыть, т.е.  по-бешеному.